# How to compile Racket Doc source file

Tags: racket

I have downloaded the source for Racket Guide to learn how it has been documented. I wanted to make changes and see how it reflects in the rendered html.

I need help in compiling the source for Racket Guide.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you said you "downloaded the source", what do you mean by that?

One way to setup Racket (and its docs) for modification is to:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/racket/racket
$ cd racket
$ make # The first run could take long time depending on your hardware. Mine took 25 mins, with multithreading enabled.
```

This will build the entire Racket and its documentation. Then, you can modify the doc. For example, to modify the Racket Guide, you should change stuff in `pkgs/racket-doc/scribblings/guide`. After that, run `make` again to render the change. You can view the updated documentation via `raco docs`.

Comment: Okay. I got it. I thought instead of building entire racket to see the changes in the racket docs there must be a local way of building the docs or in my case racket guide alone. Thanks will do that.